# Showcaseview library calling multiple times on Recyclerview's first item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, showcaseview

I am using https://github.com/florent37/TutoShowcase this showcaseview library in my code.

It works fine in `activity` and `fragment`.But when I call in `recyclerview` item it shows multiple popups and gets blackout.

```
mRecyclerViewList.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    Logger.log("Call");

                    TextView textView = (TextView) mRecyclerViewList.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.txt_add_tocart_btn);
                    Logger.log("Textview" + textView);
                    textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    TutoShowcase.from((Activity) context).setContentView(R.layout.tuto_showcase_tuto_sample)
                            .setFitsSystemWindows(true).on(textView).addRoundRect(35).showOnce("1").show();
                    // unregister listener (this is important)
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
                        mRecyclerViewList.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    } else {
                        mRecyclerViewList.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                }
            });
```

How can I avoid multiple popup's?

Comment: If your code is not calling multiple times then it should be a library issue . Ask library contributer on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question how to avoid Multiple popup's:

Just set a boolean value to avoid showing multiple times.

```
boolean isShown = false;

mRecyclerViewList.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    Logger.log("Call");
                    if(!isShown){
                      TextView textView = (TextView) mRecyclerViewList.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.txt_add_tocart_btn);
                      Logger.log("Textview" + textView);
                      textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                      TutoShowcase.from((Activity) context).setContentView(R.layout.tuto_showcase_tuto_sample)
                            .setFitsSystemWindows(true).on(textView).addRoundRect(35).showOnce("1").show();
                       isShown = true;
                     }
                    // unregister listener (this is important)
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
                        mRecyclerViewList.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    } else {
                        mRecyclerViewList.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: @SkyAlligator, Are you serious? Using of `GlobalLayoutListener` to generate hundreds of events to ignore them all except first one? Such a shame, why do people complain about apps?

Comment: please read my answer first. he asking how to avoid multiple popups in his implementation.

Comment: @NorthernPoet Read my question first.Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html) of `OnGlobalLayoutListener`:

> to be invoked when the global layout state or the visibility of views within the view tree changes.

That's why you got many and many showcase views. Every time ViewTree changed, you generate showcase.

You don't need for `ViewTreeObserver` and `GlobalLayoutListener`.

Move

```
TutoShowcase.from
```

to `onViewCreated` for example.

Comment: I am using viewTreeObserver because mRecyclerViewList.getChildAt(0) gets null.As getChildAt(0) gets call in some listener.

Comment: In `Fragment.onViewCreated` all views are constructed and allocated. Do `getChildAt` inside. And it's better to use LayoutManager's `findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition` prior.